# Magento Module Depends Throws Exception

Tags: module, magento-1, error

I'm building an extension, following the official Magento developer's guide, here: http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf

In the **app/etc/modules/Mage_Extension.xml** file, the following code results in a fatal error:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Extension>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

However, this is stipulated as a recommendation by Magento on page 8 of the guide. If I comment out the `depends` code, all is well:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Extension>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <!--
            <depends>
                <Mage_adminhtml />
            </depends>
            -->
        </Mage_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Can anyone tell me why this throws an exception and whether I should just leave it out?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't overwrite magento class and your magento extension don't depends on any extension then just leave it out

Comment: If your module uses any functionality from Mage_Adminhtml it is best pratice to set it as a depencency. Adminhtml will be there, but other modules like Mage_Poll might be deactivated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that `adminhtml` is all lowercase.
It should be:

```
<depends>
   <Mage_Adminhtml />
</depends>
```

Off topic: I hope `Mage_Extension` is just a placeholder you used for the extension name in this question. Do not use `Mage` as a namespace. Even if it works is not a good practice.

Comment: Fantastic, thx Marius. Yes, it's just a placeholder ;)